# Attachment Inherit exposed filters

Tags: 7, views

I'm trying to use an attachment to use the existing filters of blocks I have the attachment set to but for some reason it is not returning the the results related to that specific block it keeps displaying the same result in each block I have the attachment set to. I have attacked screenshots for the settings I have.

Heres the attachment[image]
and here is my block
[image]

Comment: Is it possible that inheriting the filters from the block results in the view ignoring the additional filters defined in the attachment?

Comment: That could be possible but Im not sure, how can I tell and how can I fix it?

Comment: Add another filter for the attachment (something simple like limit to one content type) and see if the display changes or not.  That will tell you if the those filters are working.

Comment: yeah your right nothing changed

Comment: Turns out that many people are having this same problem and its a bug within views.

https://drupal.org/node/898352